# How to make footer UITableViewCell not static?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I have 2 prototype dynamic cell called InvoiceDetailCell and TotalCostFooterCell. I make the TotalCostFooterCell as the Footer Cell View using `viewForFooterInSection`. here is the code I use to assign data to the UITableView

here is my code in UITableViewController.

```
extension InvoiceDetailVC : UITableViewDataSource {
    // MARK: - UI Table View Datasource Methods

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return invoiceElements.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InvoiceDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! InvoiceDetailCell
        cell.invoiceElementData = invoiceElements[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



}


extension InvoiceDetailVC : UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - UI Table View Delegate Methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "invoiceDetailFooterCell") as! TotalCostFooterCell
        cell.totalCost = singleInvoiceData.unpaid

        return cell
    }

}
```

but the result is not as I expected, I mean the footer cell is stick / not move. here is the .gif file :  http://g.recordit.co/vf0iwCfEWX.gif

you can see the total cost (red colour) is sticky / static, I want that footer cell can be scrolled and always on the bottom. or do I have the wrong to implement what I want?

[image]

Comment: **@alexa289** how were you able to get the cells to add up their total in the footer ive been trying for days to get the total to add up in the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the table style to grouped

you can do it in two ways:

1. In `viewDidLoad()` do `tableView.style = .grouped`
2. Select the table view from storyboard and in the attribute inspector change the style to grouped. Please refer attached image.[image]

Comment: glad to see that It helped :D

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make it as the last row of the table view? I mean, the view is already a table view cell, so it makes sense to use it as the last row.

First change this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return invoiceElements.count + 1
}
```

And then for `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == invoiceElements.count {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "invoiceDetailFooterCell") as! TotalCostFooterCell
        cell.totalCost = singleInvoiceData.unpaid

        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InvoiceDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! InvoiceDetailCell
    cell.invoiceElementData = invoiceElements[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your custom view that you want by:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = yourCustomView
```

Or you can put everything inside your xib/storyboard like this:

[image]